# Экранировать все запрещенные символы для следующего использования а JS

Tags: php, jquery

Имею такой код.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$("#text").val("<?=$text?>");

</script>
```

В $text попадает текст, в нем разные ссылки, символы и так далее. Как сразу все запрещение символы экранировать при помощи php чтобы потом JS их принимал?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю вам в этом направлении:

[htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

[strip-tags](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Сделал так - $text = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), '',  strip_tags($text));

Comment: @Tokwiro, можно просто `$text = preg_replace('/\s+', '', strip_tags($text));`

Comment: Сомнительная идея.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае (вставка строки в код внутри инлайнового тега `<script>`) правильным вариантом экранирования будет такой:

```
json_encode($text)
```

Дополнительные двойные кавычки при этом в коде не нужны. Также обращаю внимание, что по умолчанию php в `json_encode` экранирует `/`, что не позволит протащить инъекцию на основе `</script>`, поскольку `<\/script>` не является закрывающим тегом.

https://ideone.com/XeCoUy

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/pentestit/blog/211494/ и незачем велосипед

Comment: Что значит не применимы? 
1) Тс написал что ему подошло. 2) Тс написал про то что у него попадаются ссылки и ненужные символы,и это надо экранировать. Ему надо экранировать ВСЕ такие символы. Как мне кажется вы не поняли задачу. Да и в целом, что вы делаете не совсем понятно, когда свободно можно вставить <script src="link">

Comment: Результат php:  https://ideone.com/WA8hDH  результат в html и js строки из пыхи: 
https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Pavel, если бы вставка была не внутрь js-кода в теге script, это было бы верно. Но в скрипте html-сущности не работают и получается избыточное экранирование. Вот, я вставил оба наши варианта получившегося кода в html: https://jsfiddle.net/xfr1Lbkq/ - инъекция не прокатила в обоих случаях, но в моём в инпуте отображается ожидаемое значение, а в твоём - излишне закодированное. Про `<script src="link">` я не понял, что имеется в виду.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102529/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pavel).